# What would be the code for Click X and Y in Google Chrome iMacros?

Tags: google-chrome, imacros

For some reason this code works in Firefox but not Chrome.

```
 CLICK X=500 Y=500
```

It is giving me this error:

```
 SyntaxError: unknown command: CLICK at line 3
```

Is there a different type of command that will do the same thing for Chrome? I prefer something that will click the coordinates of the page not based on the tag or HTML code of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [iMacros command reference](http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference#iMacros_Commands_Reference), it's clear that the `CLICK` command is only supported on Firefox. The browser compatibility icons are specified at the top of the documentation, and next to `CLICK` is only the Firefox logo, as shown below.

[image: CLICK browser compatibility]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I was quite angry at this site. Well that sucks that Chrome doesn't support this. :(